# Функция fetchall() ничего не выводит

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть небольшая БД для телеграм бота в котором есть следующие столбцы:

```
id - int;  
username - text;  
group_or_name - text;   
status - int;  
chat_id - int,
```

И есть небольшой кусок кода, который должен выводить `status`. Но к сожалению функция `fetchall()` ничего не выводит, пробовал через Navicat исполнить запрос - всё прекрасно выводит

Сам код:

```
import sqlite3

message_chat_id = 445373595

def get_status(message_chat_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    check_data = cursor.execute("SELECT status FROM users WHERE chat_id = ?", (message_chat_id,))
    count_accounts = len(check_data.fetchall())
    # print(count_accounts)
    status = check_data.fetchall()
    # print(status)
    return status

get_status(message_chat_id)
```

Comment: Так же хочется отметить, что поле вытаскивается, и когда я считаю количество строк выведенных с помощью `fetchall()`, мне пишет единицу, а саму строку не показывает

Comment: `fetchall()` разгружает курсор, то есть опустошает его, по этому когда вы записываете в `count_accounts` длину, в `status` ничего не передается

Comment: `.execute()` посылает запрос в базу(его кстати не обязательно записывать в переменную), а `fetchall()` забирает себе результат, значит либо записывать `fetchall()` в переменную, а потом брать из нее длину и тд, либо каждый раз обращаться к базе по новой

Comment: @finally, спасибо огромное, третий день уже ломаю голову

Comment: сам когда то проходил это)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

message_chat_id = 445373595

def get_status(message_chat_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    check_data = cursor.execute("SELECT status FROM users WHERE chat_id = ?", (message_chat_id,))
    fetch = cursror.fetchall()
    count_accounts = len(fetch)
    return fetch

get_status(message_chat_id)
```